# Ocultar opciones en Dynamic forms - Yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

Necesito agregar una pequeña función para ocultar las opciones de `_form-opc`
al seleccionar el tipo de pregunta "sustentar" del combobox. Actualmente puedo hacerlo, pero solo de la primera manera dinámica, agradecería puedan ayudarme.

_Form

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'dynamic-form',
    "enableAjaxValidation" => true,
]);
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->input('title', ['placeholder' => "Title Evaluation"]) ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?=
                $form->field($model, 'date_start')->widget(DateTimePicker::className(), [
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => '-- Select Date --'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'language' => 'fr',
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'calendarWeeks' => true,
                        'daysOfWeekDisabled' => [0, 5],
                        'todayHighlight' => true,
                        'todayBtn' => true,
                    ]
                ]);
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?=
                $form->field($model, 'date_end')->widget(DateTimePicker::className(), [
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => '-- Select Date --'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'language' => 'fr',
                        'autoclose' => true,
                    ]
                ]);
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?=
                $form->field($model, "type_evaluation_id")->dropDownList(
                        ArrayHelper::map(EvalTipo::find()->all(), 'id', 'description'), [
                    'prompt' => '-- Select Type --'
                ]);
                ?> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <?=
                $form->field($model, 'duration')->widget(TimePicker::className(), [
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'showSeconds' => true,
                        'showMeridian' => false,
                        'minuteStep' => 1,
                        'secondStep' => 5,
                    ]
                ]);
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'qualification')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Qualification']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => 9, 'placeholder' => 'Enter evaluation description']) ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="box box-success box-solid">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title">Questions Evaluation</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php
            DynamicFormWidget::begin([
                'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
                'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
                'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
                'limit' => 30, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
                'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
                'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
                'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
                'model' => $modelQuestion[0],
                'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
                'formFields' => [
                    'item',
                    'puntuacion',
                ],
            ]);
            ?>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Question</th>
                        <th style="width: 500px;">Options</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width: 90px;">
                            <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="container-items">
                    <?php foreach ($modelQuestion as $indexQuestion => $modelQuestions): ?>
                        <tr class="item">
                            <td class="vcenter">
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                    <td class="vcenter">1.</td>
                                    <td class="vcenter">
                                        <?php
                                        // necessary for update action.
                                        if (!$modelQuestions->isNewRecord) {
                                            echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelQuestions, "[{$indexQuestion}]id");
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                        <?= $form->field ( $modelQuestion , "[{$indexQuestion}]question" )->dropDownList (
                                                ArrayHelper::map(QuestType::find()->all() , 'id' , 'description' ) , [
                                            'prompt' => '-- Select Question --'
                                        ] ); ?>
                                        <?= $form->field($modelQuestions, "[{$indexQuestion}]question")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Title question']) ?>
                                       <?= $form->field($modelQuestions, "[{$indexQuestion}]score")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Score']) ?><?= $form->field($modelQuestions,"[{$indexQuestion}]justified ")->checkbox(array('label'=>'','labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'padding:5px;'),                    ))->label('You want a response justified ?');?>
                                    </td>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=
                                $this->render('_form-opc', [
                                    'form' => $form,
                                    'indexEvaPr' => $indexQuestion,
                                    'modelsOpc'=>$modelsOpc[$indexQuestion],
                                ])
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-center vcenter" style="width: 90px; verti">
                                <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? '<span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Crear' : '<span class="fa fa-edit"></span>  Modificar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

_form-opc

```
<?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_inner',
'widgetBody' => '.container-opciones',
'widgetItem' => '.opcion-item',
'limit' => 10,
'min' => 2,
'insertButton' => '.add-opcion',
'deleteButton' => '.remove-opcion',
'model' => $modelsOpc[0],
'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
'formFields' => [
    'titulo',
],
```

]); ?>

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th class="text-center">
            <button type="button" class="add-opcion btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="container-opciones">
<?php foreach ($modelsOpc as $indexOpc => $modelOpc): ?>
    <tr class="opcion-item">
        <td class="vcenter">
            <?php
                // necessary for update action.
                if (! $modelOpc->isNewRecord) {
                    echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelOpc, "[{$indexQuestion}][{$indexOpc}]id");
                }
            ?>
            <?= $form->field($modelOpc, "[{$indexQuestion}][{$indexOpc}]option")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Title option']) ?>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center vcenter" style="width: 90px;">
            <button type="button" class="remove-opcion btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

JS

```
$script = <<< JS

    $(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("change","select",function(){
            var id=$(this).attr("id");
            var optionsInput=id.match(/^([a-zA-Z]+)\-([0-9]+)/g)[0]+'-justified';

            if ($(this).val()== 3) {
                $('#'+optionsInput).hide().attr('disabled',true);
                $('#options-0-0-option').attr('disabled',true).hide();
            }else {
                $('#'+optionsInput).show().attr('disabled',false);
                $('#options-0-0-option').attr('disabled',false).show();

           }

    });
```

JS;
?>

lo que planeo conseguir

[Mostrar opciones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWfTC.png)

[Ocultar opciones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFzCg.png)

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, podrías reformularla y explicar de alguna otra manera más detallada?

Comment: Buenas, lo que quiero es ocultar las opciones de una pregunta que sea del tipo "Sustentar" , por ejemplo tengo tipo de preguntas que son "opciones múltiples", "única opción" y "sustentar". al escoger cualquiera de las 2 primeras puedo agregar las opciones que desee pero al escoger "sustentar" esta no me permita agregar opciones ya que esta sera para que uno pueda justificar una pregunta.

Comment: Y ahorita ya tienes un js por lo que veo, te marca algún error o que pasa?

Comment: Lo que quiero obtener es el id del input "option" que esta en la vista _form-opc. si te fijas en el js puedo ocultar el check box  por id "justified" en cada pregunta que valla agregando, lo que quiero es que sea igual pero en este caso para las opciones.